# How to create jboss-all.xml in ear with maven pom?

Tags: maven, jboss, pom.xml, wildfly

I need a jboss-all.xml file in my META-INF. But the ear is created with POM ear plugin. How can I add a jboss-all.xml file with custom configurations by configuring POM.XML? Thank you!

Comment: Do you already have a jboss-all.xml in your project? Do you just need to add it to the EAR file, under META-INF? Or do you need it to be created during the build of the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out that I can just add the jboss-all.xml to src/main/resources/META-INF and it will be there in the ear.